# Contador de datos en una lista que contiene 3 matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matrices

Tengo una lista con 3 matrices de 20x20, al principio tenia que llenar estas matrices con 0 y después llenarlas con números aleatorios entre el 0 y 101 (excluyentes). Eso ya lo logre pero ahora tengo que hacer un contador que me entregue lo siguiente:

visualizar cuantas veces aparece un numero ingresado por el terminal en cada matriz y cuantas veces aparece en total (en toda la lista).

Les dejo lo que hice, pero dudo que este bien:

```
def buscar_n_elemento(lista1, e):
   contador=0
   for i in lista1:
      if i == e:
         contador+=1
   return contador

print(buscar_n_elemento)
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una posible solución, primero inicializamos las matrices de 20x20 de forma aleatoria, y definimos la función para recorrer la lista con las 3 matrices y encontrar el elemento buscado.

```
import random

def buscar_n_elemento(l,e):
    num = 0
    for matriz in l:
        for i in range(len(matriz)):
            for j in range(len(matriz[i])):
                if (e == matriz[i][j]):
                    num = num + 1
    return num


n = 20
m = 20

lt_1 = list()
lt_2 = list()
lt_3 = list()
lt_t = list()

for i in range(n):
    lt_1.append([])
    lt_2.append([])
    lt_3.append([])
    for j in range(m):
        lt_1[i].append(random.randint(0,100))
        lt_2[i].append(random.randint(0,100))
        lt_3[i].append(random.randint(0,100))

lt_t.append(lt_1)
lt_t.append(lt_2)
lt_t.append(lt_3)

#buscamos el 34 por ejemplo
na = int(input("¿Qué número quiere buscar? "))
ve = buscar_n_elemento(lt_t,na)
print(na, " ha sido encontrado ", ve, " veces ")
```

Comment: Gracias! Y como hago para que el numero en la lista buscada sea preguntado para el usuario? Osea que el usuario ponga que numero desea encontrar

Comment: @Friner cambia `na=34` por `na = int(input("que número quiere buscar? "))`

Comment: Por certo tambien puedes usar *f-strings*

Comment: Muchas Gracias! ya pude solucionar mi pregunta

Comment: @Friner puedes marcar la respuesta como válida.